# Air Native Menu

Tags: actionscript-3, menu, air

I have an Air windowedapplication with no chrome (but a custom) and main app windows is transparent.

I try to attach a nativeMenu on nativeWindow (or nativeApplication on Mac Os). But as there is no system chrome NativeMenu don't work on windows Os but work well on Mac Os.

As I'd like to have similar look and feel on both Os, is someone has an idea to solve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of information available on [NativeMenu](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/NativeMenu.html) at Adobe's site. I'd create the menu and try to attach it to nativeWindow/nativeApplication. If it fails, use *NativeMenu.display()* method to show the menu manualy if it isn't supported on certain system(s).

Also if you need working Keyboard shortcuts for that menu, listen for Keyboard events.